# Number of combinations of increasing tuples given their sum

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, combinations, recursive-algorithms

A tuple is represented by 
$(a_i,a_{i-1},...,a_1)$ where $a_i<a_{i-1}$ and $i \in \{2...N\}$

So, valid tuples are $(1,2,3,4)$ and $(2,5,9,41)$

You are given the sum of these tuples

$a_i + a_{i-1} + \ldots +a_1 = S$

Can you compute in how many ways these tuples can be organized so that the  order is increasing.

**For example**

If the sum is 5, then there are 2 ways to organize the tuples

$(1,4)$ and $(2,3)$

If the sum is 10, then there are 9 ways to organize the tuples

$(1,9)$, $(2,8)$, $(3,7)$, $(4,6)$, $(1,2,7)$, $(1,3,6)$, $(1,4,5)$, $(2,3,5)$ and $(1,2,3,4)$

Can you come up with any general formula to calculate that?

I was able to come with a recursive algorithm that generates all the sequences, however, it is too slow.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are talking about a form of [Partitions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) without repitition of individual numbers. What you can do in your case is calculate the number of tuples for an initial number. In your case, it would be $3$. From there, you calculate the number of partitions of order two as $\left\lfloor\frac n 2\right\rfloor-1$. You can calculate the number of partitions of order three by choosing a number $m$ and finding all partitions of $n-m$ such that all values used in the partition are greater than $m$. You continue on from there until you reach $k$ numbers in the tuple such that $n\geq\frac{k(k+1)}2$.

Comment: I don't really understand the following part. Can you please give me an example of what you mean exactly?
_You can calculate the number of partitions of order three by choosing a number $m$ and finding all partitions of $n−m$ such that all values used in the partition are greater than $m$._

Let's say you are looking at n = 10, then what would m be when looking for partitions with order 3

Comment: You choose $m=1$, then you find the number of partitions for $9$ that don't use any number below $1$.

Comment: Got you. The problem with this approach is that you still need to generate the tuples. I was hoping that I can avoid doing that. This is again slow.

Comment: You shouldn't need to explicitly calculate the tuples, just the number of tuples.

Answer (score 0):

This is one less than the [number of partitions of $S$ into distinct parts](https://oeis.org/A000009).